Сделать доступным GPU в google colab с Tensorflow 2.13
По умолчанию, в настоящее время в google colab сейчас предустановлен Tensorflow 2.15.0 и в меню можно выбрать Runtime -> Change runtime type видеокарту
Но если необходим Tensorflow 2.13.0, его можно установить, но тогда перестает быть доступным GPU.

Есть ли возможность использования в google-colab Tensorflow 2.13.0 c GPU и как это сделать?
